# Problem in beamer class linebreak in footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I encountered a strange definition in the footline environment of beamer.
Here is a minimal example, which shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},rgb]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
   \leavevmode%
   \hfill\rule{0.89\textwidth}{0.2pt}\hfill \\
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=4cm,leftskip=0.5cm,sep=10pt]{page number}
    \insertframenumber
   \end{beamercolorbox}
   \hspace*{4cm}}%
\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Behind the rule there will be printed a ",". This is due to the defintion of \ \ in the footline.
I have got one solution for the problem:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
   \leavevmode%
   \hfill\rule{0.89\textwidth}{0.2pt}\hfill\hfill\textcolor{white}{ }
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=4cm,leftskip=0.5cm,sep=10pt]{page number}
      \insertframenumber
    \end{beamercolorbox}
   \hspace*{4cm}}
```

Is there a better solution for that problem and why is the \ \ redefined in the footline.

Comment: Maybe `\hfill\rule{0.89\textwidth}{0.2pt}\hfill\ \newline` or `\hfill\rule{0.89\textwidth}{0.2pt}\hfill\hfill\newline`

Comment: @Benjamin Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 4):

**Converting [@Benjamins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283342/problem-in-beamer-class-linebreak-in-footline#comment683501_283342) comment into a CW answer:**

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},rgb]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
   \leavevmode%
   \hfill\rule{0.89\textwidth}{0.2pt}\hfill\ \newline
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=4cm,leftskip=0.5cm,sep=10pt]{page number}
    \insertframenumber
   \end{beamercolorbox}
   \hspace*{4cm}}%
\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]